# Make surface view transparent to current layout only

Tags: android, surfaceview, transparent

In my app i am using surface view for drawing perspective and some buttons on the same layout.
I am done with the drawing part but don't know how to make surface view transparent for the current layout only.

When i use holder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT); it shows my previous screen.

I have also tried the setZOrderOnTop(true); method but it makes my other buttons hidden/covered when drawing.

And using setZOrderMediaOverlay(true); put the view beyond current layout, if i am moving my finger over the screen it is drawing there as i can see the saved file, but not showing on screen.

I want to make it transparent for current screen without setting the z order.

Forks, help me to make this happen.
Thanks in advance.